# How to set a path parameter using the AsyncHttpClient library

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I am using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) for making HTTP calls. I am unable to find a solution to set a path parameter in a URL. Here is an example:

```
userId = "dmsask121"
String v3_USER_DETAILS = "http://example.com/users/{userId}/details";
Request request = new RequestBuilder(HttpConstants.Methods.GET)
        .setUrl(v3_USER_DETAILS)
        // some way to set userId in the URL??
        .build();
return execute(request)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is an HTTP client, not a REST client.  Try okhttp, which allows construction of an url instead or jax-rs

Comment: or just `setUrl(v3_USER_DETAILS.replace("{userId}", userId))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the library's code, and it looks like it doesn't support inserting path parameters into URLs. You can easily add a query parameter using `addQueryParam(String name, String value)`, but there is no method to insert a path parameter as in your example. You have to prepare the whole path part another way, for example, using `String::replace()` as suggested in a comment.